# IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Java

Tags: java, enums

I have this code (it's a java class called TshirtSearcher) that is trying to grab the t-shirt size info from a text file and put it in a enum called Size:

```
for (int i = 1; i < TShirtData.size(); i++) {
        //split each String in the list by [ and , to separate the t-shirt name,product code,price,brand, from sizes,description
        String[] elements = TShirtData.get(i).split("\\[");
        //separate the t-shirt info by splitting by comma. This will separate the following; name,product code,price,brand into individual items
        String[] tshirtInfo = elements[0].split(",");
        String name = tshirtInfo[0];
        long productCode = 0;
        try {
            productCode = Long.parseLong(tshirtInfo[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
            System.out.println("Error in file. Product code could not be parsed for t-shirt on line " + (i + 1) + ". Terminating. \nError message: " + n.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Read the data from the file as enum
        Size size = Size.valueOf(elements[1].replace("],", ""));
```

This is the enum:

```
public enum Size {

XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL, XXXXL;

/**
 * @return a prettified version of the relevant enum constant
 */
public String toString() {
    return switch (this) {
        case XS -> "Extra Small";
        case S -> "Small";
        case M -> "Medium";
        case L -> "Large";
        case XL -> "Extra Large";
        case XXL -> "2x Extra Large";
        case XXXL -> "3x Extra Large";
        case XXXXL -> "4x Extra Large";
    };
}
```

However, when I run the code it gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Size.S,M,L,XL,XXL
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:273)
    at Size.valueOf(Size.java:6)
    at TShirtSearcher.loadTShirts(TShirtSearcher.java:45)
    at TShirtSearcher.main(TShirtSearcher.java:121)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

The file content is like this (just show the first 3 rows):

name,product code,price,brand,sizes,description

hello world,852760540,34.96,Tommy Bugfinder,[S,M,L,XL,XXL],[Graphic text: "Hello world"]

The Simpsons,576857394,22.99,Lacoder,[S,M,L],[Graphic text: "Worst. Episode. Ever."]

---

I would like the user to be able to select the size from the dropdown menu.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message means that you are passing the string `S,M,L,XL,XXL` to `Size.valueOf()`. That doesn't work because `S,M,L,XL,XXL` is not one of the enum constants. Debug your application to find out why it's passing the wrong thing to `Size.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jesper and @Davide :-)
I've solved it by creating a list of split elements:

```java
String[] sizeSplit = elements[1].split(",");
Size size = Size.valueOf(sizeSplit[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

On this record

```
hello world,852760540,34.96,Tommy Bugfinder,[S,M,L,XL,XXL],[Graphic text: "Hello world"]
```

you have a record S,M,L,XL,XXL but on your enum you haven't declered the value.

Maybe there are a error on desing.

please try to change in:

```
hello world,852760540,34.96,Tommy Bugfinder,[S],[Graphic text: "Hello world"]
```

and try a debug test.

Comment: Thanks Davide, By changing the file seems to be working, so I need to find out how to make it work without touching the file

Comment: Update, if I change to S it works for the first row, and then it gives me error again for the second row. I presume I have to split [S,M,L,XL,XXL] in single chars. maybe?

Comment: Yes, implement a loop on your List [S,M,L,XL,XXL] and for each value call Size.ValueOf(), and use the response for your logic.